# A for loop with a logic or a syntax issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax, logic

So I'm trying to push the length of an array as a string onto another array.
My logic is this... for javascript

```
if    x = [1];
and   y = [1];
```

and I want to push x.length + 1 to the y array in a for loop so it becomes 
1
12
123
1234

this is how I'm trying to do it but getting a read out of

```
function push() { [native code] } function push() { [native code] } function push() { [native code] } function push() { [native code] }
```

here is my code

```
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {

        var x = [1];
        var y = [1];

            document.writeln(y.push.toString(x.length + 1));

    };
```

is this a logic error or a syntax error?

Comment: What do you expect `y.push.toString` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are trying to do this

```
    var x = [1];
    var y = [1];
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
       document.writeln(y.push(x.length + 1));
};
```

or

```
var x = [1];
var y = [1];
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        y.push(y.length + 1)
        document.writeln(y);
    }
```

or

```
var y = ""
for (i=1; i < 100; i++) {
        y += i
        document.writeln(y);
}
```

Comment: The last one hits it perfectly

Comment: the last one was how I would do it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

you are writing y.push.toString

Try:

```
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = [1];
    var y = [1];
    y.push(x.length + 1)
    document.writeln(y);
};
```

But I think what you meant was [JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/inomen/1/edit):

```
var y = [];    
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    y.push(y.length + 1)
    document.writeln(y + '<br/>');
};
```

Comment: That's a lot like what I ended up figuring out

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is what you want:

```
var y = [1];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var x = y[y.length-1].toString() + (y.length + 1);
    y.push(x);
} 
document.writeln(y.toString());
```

Comment: I like it, that's what i was trying to do. I figured out another another way too that puts a comma between each number. See my answer below

Comment: I don't think you can add a break to this and have each number on it's own row

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it

```
var y = [1];
    document.writeln(y + '<br>');
for (i=2; i < 101; i++) {
    y.push(i);
    document.writeln(y + '<br>' );
};
```